# Haskell calculator

Tags: haskell

Here is my new main with the `error: parse error on input '->'`
I commented where the error is. Could it be an indentation error somewhere?

```
main :: IO()
main = do
  expression <- evaluate_input
  putStrLn $ show $ compute expression

evaluate_input :: IO ()
evaluate_input = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    a:s -> return a
    -> do putStrLn "Enter Expression or 'end' to exit calculator"
           hFlush stdout
           getLine
           unless (expression -> "end") $ showExpr expression --error here
  where
    showExpr expression = do putStrLn $ evaluateExpr expression
                        evaluate_input
evaluateExpr :: String -> String
evaluateExpr = show
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to compile or run this? It's good to post the specific issue in the question to give people as much information as possible.

Comment: Your case syntax is wrong. You should use `_ ->` when you don't care with what it matches with. Also use `do` when you need to put multiple statements after a case pattern match.

Comment: Okay I think the _ -> worked thanks for that but I was confused the second half of your comment involving the 'do'? Do I use it like this:
do putStrLn "Enter Expression or 'end' to exit calculator"

or in a different spot?

Comment: @user2106089 you can do something like this in case `_ -> putStrLn "blah"` but when you want to put multiple statements you need to use do like `_ -> do putStrLn "blah" <nextline and indented> putStrLn "blah2"`

Comment: Okay Ive been playing with it and I'm still getting a parse error. I'll modify my code up top so you can see if I'm doing it with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Few problems with your code

- `until` is not used correctly. I find it better to recurse when I have to repeat same action again and again. You can write the monadic version of `until` and use that.
- It is better to use `getArgs` inside main once. You don't need to repeat it every time.

A corrected version is here. I haven't implemented all the functions so you still need to do the hard work of parsing and evaluating expressions.

```
import Control.Monad (unless)

main :: IO ()
main = evaluate

evaluate :: IO ()
evaluate = do
  putStrLn "Enter Expression"
  expr <- getLine
  unless (expr == "end") $ showExpr expr
 where
   showExpr expr = do putStrLn $ evaluateExpr expr
                      evaluate

evaluateExpr :: String -> String
evaluateExpr = show
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I finished evaluating expression but I can't figure out how to set the unless function

Comment: @user2106089 I am not clear what do you mean by setting `unless`. The type of `unless` is `unless :: Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()`. It performs the action(second argument) if the value of first argument is `True` otherwise do `return ()`.

Comment: I changed up my main a bit and now I'm getting this error: 
Parse error in pattern: expression == "end"
heres my main and ill comment where the error is

Comment: @user2106089 Can you paste that to hpaste. It is not very clear to understand the code in comments.